# How to delete multiple sub folders in Outlook, in one go?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

In Outlook 2007, is there a way to delete multiple sub folders under a given folder in one go?
I would like to keep a few sub folders and delete the rest. How can I do it in one fell swoop, instead of selecting each sub folder and deleting it?
There must be an easier way...

Comment: I'm guessing you've tried selecting all the subfolders then hitting delete?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, there is no direct way of deleting multiple folders in Outlook. One workaround would be to:

1. Create a *temp* folder.
2. Drag all the folders you want to delete to the *temp* folder.
3. Delete the *temp* folder

Comment: This sounds like a reasonable workaround. I just wish Outlook wasn't so full of these sort of flaws.

Comment: But then you have to DRAG each Folder... remains Kind of the same effort.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Outlook 2007, but unless it's drastically different from regular Windows programs, `Control-click` and `Shift-click` should let you select multiple subfolders.

Comment: Nope. That doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try moving the subfolders you'd like to keep somewhere else and deleting everything else you have in the folder. This would be easy if you only want to keep a small number of subfolders, otherwise it's not really worth it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool called [Pandali Folder Master for Outlook](http://pandali.com/pfm.html) which allows you to select multiple folders by clicking checkboxes or Shift+Clicking to select a range, and then you can copy, move, or delete them.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and quickest way I found to do this was to condense the folders down to one or a few and then delete that folder with all its sub-folders.

You can do this simply by dragging and dropping one folder into another. This method also allows you to pick and choose quickly which folders to delete and which ones to keep.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there is the [**free** Delete Outlook Subfolders tool](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookFolderDeleteSubfolders) that does exactly want.